# How to handle the path variable with space

Tags: linux, bash, shell, path, command

`foldername=$(echo 'A A_2016' | cut -f 1 -d '_')
mv "$filename" $foldername/`
foldername is 'A A' there is a space, so how to handle this.
Thanks.

Comment: It is unclear what you ask. Why can't you simply use `mv "$filename" A\ A_2016/` or  `mv "$filename" A\ A/`?

Comment: I get a string from somewhere, then split it to get the folder name, so I don't know the folder name before I split it, can not use your way to fix.

Answer (score 0):

Just use quotes around the variables:

```
mv "$filename" "$foldername/"
```

Answer (score 0):

just put a back slash as below:
let your folder name is "new folder" and path is usr/etc/new folder

```
mv aa.txt  usr/etc/new\ folder
```

if you are using variable use it as

```
mv aa.txt "$FOLDERNAME/"
```

Comment: But I get the folder name from a String, so I don't know whether if the folder name contains space.it is black box for me

Comment: add " " with varible name as "$foldername/"

Answer (score 0):

You have to use backslash followed by white-space. For example, you have to write `A\ A_2016`.

Answer (score 0):

Sample file created:

```
touch 'A A_2016'
ls -1
A A_2016
```

Name check of sample file:

```
echo ${file}
A A_2016
```

Moving it after chopping it using variable expansion.

```
mv "${file}" "${file##* }"
ls -1
A_2016
```